# JupyterHub with multi user and GPU for kubernetes

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, jupyterhub

I need an image with JupyterHub configured to multiple users and GPU with tensorFlow 10.1 or 11, any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

**GPU Image**: modify the `base-notebook` in the `jupyter-stacks` to be FROM the nvidia cuda repository instead of ubuntu. Your nodes must be GPU enabled with nvidia-docker installed.

**Hub**: Follow installation guide on https://zero-to-jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/